# sitefinity register users control

Tags: sitefinity

Within sitefinity there is a build in control that will register users  and add them into the `sf_sitefinity_profile` table. I been looking for that line of code but I am unable to find it. Is there anywy I can find it? I can't see the controller for this register users control is that in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to probably do that stuff in the UserEvents not in a control.

https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-user-events